# Request OAuth token from BitBucket

Tags: php, curl, oauth, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I've been trying to integrate BitBucket to my application for the past 4 hours to no avail.

While reading through [BitBucket's RESTful API documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+bitbucket+REST+APIs), I noticed that you need to use OAuth — it's OK, I'm using J.R Conlin's [OAuthSimple](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/) library, which if fine by me (I tried [oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) but it was kinda complicated — I didn't need all of those options for such a small integration).

For what I understand, the first step to authenticate with OAuth is to request a new token via POST. When providing the necessary parameters, you should get a response from BitBucket, like this:

`oauth_token=Z6eEdO8lOmk394WozF9oJyuAv899l4llqo7hhlSLik&oauth_token_secret=Jd79W4OQfb2oJTV0vzGzeXftVAwglnEJ9lumzYcl&oauth_callback_confirmed=true`

To do that, I'm using cURL and OAuthSimple:

```
$key    = 'key_provided_by_bitbucket';
$secret = 'key_provided_by_bitbucket';
$path   = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/oauth/request_token';

$params = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key'        => $key,
    'oauth_nonce'               => base_convert(mt_rand(10000, 90000), 10, 32) . 'a',
    'oauth_signature'           => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_signature_method'    => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp'           => time(),
    'oauth_callback'            => base_url('dashboard'),
    'oauth_version'             => '1.0a'
);

$oauth  = new OAuthSimple($key, $secret);
$result = $oauth->sign(array(
    'action'        => 'POST',
    'path'          => $path,
    'parameters'    => $params
));

// load resulting url into a string
$ch = curl_init($result['signed_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The thing is that, when I send my request, one of two things happen:

1. If I send it like posted here, I will get a 401 error (I can see that via curl_getinfo($ch))
2. If I set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1), I get a 400 Bad request

The resulting string (stored in `$r`) is an empty string. The `signed_url` is a correctly formed URL AFAIK, which is something like this:

`https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fidv&oauth_consumer_key=key_provided_by_bitbucket&oauth_nonce=b47a&oauth_signature=3A1R%2FoKxTqh6Q23poaS%2BVNzhwpE%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1347167282&oauth_version=1.0a`

If I enter manually that address into my address bar in a browser, I'll get an Authentication Dialog to the BitBucket API, port 443. I can't login with my credentials, though. Then it will just keep saying "Could not verify OAuth request."

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, since it's my first time using OAuth.

Any help's appreciated!

Comment: any luck on this? I'm getting the same error as you...

Comment: @ericbae I ended up having a conversation with BitBucket's Technical Support — it turns out that they had outdated information in their manual, and it was corrected. As soon as they told me that (and I made the necessary path changes) everything worked like a charm. Make sure you're using the correct paths (cause [OAuthSimple](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/) works great)

Comment: @AeroCross are you able to put your answer and or the correct paths that resulted in your fix?

Comment: i believe your talking about the $path above which should be 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token' if anyone else is viewing this, its goes through ok but i keep getting the 'Could not verify OAuth request' message now any lick on the same issue your having

Comment: I have switched over to https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ and found tis to be better and easier

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Curl will verify the SSL certificate.

To solve the problem you can tell Curl to ignore the verification of the SSL certificates:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```